# How to save data from HTML form to text file with node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I want to download text from HTML form to .txt file on my PC. I have tried many ways but nothing works well:

1. require(fs) doesn't work with the browser, as far as I understand
2. require(browserify-fs) saves file in VIRTUAL MEMORY (as far as I understand), so it useless for me
3. last way I found - using PHP script(I found it in net), but it doesn't work, idk why. I have tried to fix it - nothing, I know nothing about PHP

*program.php*

```
<?PHP
  $title = $_POST["channel0Title"]; 
  $gain = $_POST["channel0Gain"];
  $offset = $_POST["channel0Offset"];
  $file = fopen('1.txt', 'w'); 
  ftruncate($file, 0); 
  $content = $title. PHP_EOL .$gain. PHP_EOL .$offset;
  fwrite($file , $content); 
  fclose($file ); 
  die(header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]));
?>
```

*main.html*

```
    <form action="public\scripts\program.php" method="post">
        Channel 8 Title:<br><input type="text" name="channel0Title" value="Channel 7"><br>
        Gain:<br><input type="text" name="channel0Gain" value="4.000"><br>
        Offset:<br><input type="text" name="channel0Offset" value= "6.000"><br>
        <input type="submit" id ="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I have a error **Cannot POST /public/scripts/program.php**

Could you help me please why such a script doesn't work
Or maybe give advice on what language or framework should I use to simplify data transfer between client and server

Thank you in advance!

P.S. I use Node.js, so load program.php as a static file

Comment: Why are you mixing up PHP with Node server? Choose one and stick to it.

Comment: Study some tutorials on processing form data in node and file writing in node

Comment: I can not find how to cope with it using the only node.js

Comment: It sounds like you just need to print the input with additional headers

Comment: Show us an example of how you just print the form input in NodeJS, and you will get an answer pretty quickly

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate what do you mean?
All code related to form is in my post